# OperatingSystemMXBean getSystemCpuLoad and getProcessCpuLoad values

Tags: java, linux, centos, cpu-usage

I have a java program which require around 5-10% cpu most of the time. I get this information using `OperatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad`

Sometimes `OperatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad` returns a value around 0.7-0.8(70-80%) and `OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad` = 1(100%).

Initially I though there is a glitch in my program that requires so much cpu, but when I checked the `top` command in linux console , the java process was around 5-6%.

Now here is the weird part. In Linux console I do:

```
sar -u 2 5
```

and I get

```
07:33:10 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
07:33:12 AM     all      2.02      0.00      1.01     96.46      0.51      0.00
07:33:14 AM     all      1.52      0.00      1.02     96.95      0.51      0.00
07:33:16 AM     all      8.16      0.00      2.04     89.29      0.51      0.00
07:33:18 AM     all      7.07      0.00      9.60     82.32      1.01      0.00
07:33:20 AM     all      4.57      0.00      0.51     94.42      0.51      0.00
Average:        all      4.67      0.00      2.84     91.89      0.61      0.00
```

The idle is at 0%; Is the `OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad` calculated like this: `100-idle` ?

Now if I kill a process ( it doesn't matter what process), for example I restart nginx, which consumes around 1% cpu.

```
service nginx restart
```

running `sar -u 2 5`

will  get me the following result

```
07:34:49 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
07:34:51 AM     all      4.04      0.00      1.52      0.00      0.51     93.94
07:34:53 AM     all      1.02      0.00      0.51      0.51      0.51     97.46
07:34:55 AM     all      2.53      0.00      1.52      0.00      0.00     95.96
07:34:57 AM     all      2.51      0.00      2.01      1.01      1.01     93.47
07:34:59 AM     all      3.54      0.00      2.53     20.71      0.51     72.73
Average:        all      2.73      0.00      1.62      4.44      0.51     90.71
```

Idle is around 90% and then `OperatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad` and `OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad` return to normal values , around 5-10%;

I used nginx as an example, you can kill any other process, the effect is the same. I don't have any cpu hungry processes running. All processes are around 1-2% cpu, the java process is the most hungry one, but no more than 10-12%, with an average or 5-6%.

Official doc about getSystemCpuLoad : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad--

Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using CentOS 6.5

Comment: wow, this still exist in jdk15, 100% system load, without any real load